# Spotlight crashes from API misuse

Tags: macos, spotlight

In the last couple of days I have seen problems with Spotlight where it closes the search window after a random amount of keystrokes. Today I found more than 20 crash dumps and the funny thing is the share a common trait, namely this information string:

`XPC API Misuse: Release of last reference on a suspended connection.`

When I open the crash logs they all have the same top part of the crash log:

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        6  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
XPC API Misuse: Release of last reference on a suspended connection.

Application Specific Signatures:
API Misuse
```

I have tried a number of searches but not found anything that explains, nor helps me with this. Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems to be more related to Safari 12 than Spotlight in itself. If I turn off the indexing option in Spotlight for "Bookmarks and history" the problem disappears; if I leave it on Spotlight keeps crashing randomly when entering characters in the search box.

Comment: This was probably also related to a developer's release of Safari 12; with the current version this behaviour seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on macOS Sierra. It started after Safari was updated to version 12.
I found a workaround by disabling a QuickLook plug-in.

You have to disable the SIP (System Integry Protection) first.
After that you can rename the folder

```
/System/Library/QuickLook/Clippings.qlgenerator
```

to

```
/System/Library/QuickLook/Clippings.qlgenerator.old
```

Then you force reload the quicklook generators list with this command in a terminal window

```
qlmanage -r
```

You can now enable the SIP